# Eigenvalue corresponding to the stationary state

Tags: mathematical-physics, diffusion

If $M$ denotes the transition matrix of a Markov chain, then the vector $x$ that satisfies $Mx=x$ is the stationary distribution or [stationary state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_state). However, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.06949.pdf) seems to use the term stationary state in a different sense, wherein the stationary state satisfies $Mx=0$ (see Equation 4). What is the difference in the physical interpretation between the stationary state referring to the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 1 and one which corresponds to the eigenvalue 0? Is there a possible explanation for the use of the same terminology to mean different things? Terminology for something as basic as a Markov chain would have been uniform at this point.

Comment: comment on v1 of this question: I think you might be getting your links mixed up. You seem to be referring to an equation from the first link in the sentence containing the second link. Further, both of your links contain the same definition of a stationary state (namely $Mx = 0$).

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer my own question since I was able to find the answer very shortly, after bit of searching on Google.

If $x$ is the stationary state, then the *usual* Markov matrix or transition matrix satisfies $Mx=x$. In other words, $M_{ij}$ is just the transition probability from state $i$ to $j$.

There is another matrix associated with the same Markov chain called the *[generator matrix](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_3_3_the_generator_matrix.php)* which satisfies $Nx=0$ where $N_{ij}=M_{ij}$ if $i\neq j$ and $N_{ii}=- \sum_j M_{ij}$. Unfortunately, the generator matrix is also sometimes called the *Markov matrix* or *transition matrix*.